# Ansible: How to get a registered variable into a python script

Tags: python, json, ansible

I have a simple Ansible playbook that uses the raw module to list the installed choco packages on my windows clients. It looks like this:

```
- name: Get info
  hosts: win_clones
  tasks:
    - name: Get packages list installed on clients ...
      raw: choco list -lo
      register: result0
    - debug: msg="{{result0}}"
```

Since I am running this playbook from a python script I would like to get the content of the registered variable into a python variable that I can use into my script. Normally the registered variable is printed on the screen as JSON format. I would like to grab the name of the client and the content of stdout_lines. Here is the result of my playbook:

```
ok: [cl1] => {
"msg": {
    "changed": false, 
    "rc": 0, 
    "stderr": "", 
    "stdout": "chocolatey 0.9.9.11\r\nnotepadplusplus 6.9\r\nnotepadplusplus.install 6.9\r\n3 packages installed.\r\n", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "chocolatey 0.9.9.11", 
        "notepadplusplus 6.9", 
        "notepadplusplus.install 6.9", 
        "3 packages installed."

    ]
}
```

}

Would that be possible? How should I proceed? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make a [callback plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#callbacks) which extracts the value of interest and saves that to a file you can read back later.

Here is an example [playbook result log callback](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/log_plays.py)

Comment: I am running ansible 2.1.0.0, is this working also for this version? thanks

Comment: This particular example might not work, but there is also [this json example](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/json.py) and a whole bunch of other [examples](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/).